# Name of Windows "Fieldset" Control

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

In the below image,

[image: what is this called?]

there are two "wrappers" around elements:

1. General Options
2. Access Control

It shows a "section title" and wraps around the controls in that "section". I'm aware that in the context of HTML forms this is properly called a "fieldset", but searching Google and SO for "wxPython fieldset" yields no useful results in the first several pages for me.

My questions:

1. What is that called (the proper term for the GUI element/control)?
2. Is there a corresponding wxPython control to do the same concept (just the name and link to wxPython Phoenix docs is fine)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This control is a [wxStaticBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_static_box.html).